# realtime listening GET parameter on python

Tags: python, html, flask, raspberry-pi, wsgi

I had a pi-copter project. My idea to control it is using web page. I have done it using php. But the copter running gyro sensor to makes it stable while flying. So, to run and get data from the sensor, it have to be programmed. I using python to run the sensor. the script will process a control to esc from orientation and from data that I sends using front-end web page.

my question is how python listens GET data from front-end web page?

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and update your question with specifics.

Comment: Please edit your question and try to better explain what you're trying to do. What does the web server need to do? What does the GPIO need to do?

Comment: If you want to learn the basic of how web servers work and web applications work, read https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part1/. Then go look at Flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/) as a simple way of getting into Python web programming. Easier if you ditch your PHP and do it all in Python, that way the sensor control code is just a part of the Python web application. Expect to have to learn stuff by reading rather than getting quick answers here. Have fun.